# A .Click function not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What I need:**

I need the button2 to appear when button1 is clicked. NEW STUFF: What I need it to do is save button2 there so if you refresh or "run" button 2 is already there how would I do that?

**What I've done/Tried:**

I've tried a bunch of different things such as changing it around changing the scope, as well as checking for console errors, I get none so I'm not too sure what is going on.

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button2').hide();
  window.highestLevel = 1;

$('#button1').click(function () {
    Check();
    highestLevel = 2;
});

  if (highestLevel == 2) {
    $('#button2').show();
}

function Check() {
    localStorage.setItem('highestLevel', highestLevel);
  }

});
```

**WHAT WORKS**

The only thing that works is it stores it correctly to the html local storage when I click `$('#button1')`.

**Link** , ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6L16556/5/)***

Comment: I've updated the **What I need:** section

Comment: To maintain information between page refresh/reload events, storing some data in local storage/cookies would be the only answer.

Comment: Rather than change the question so drastically, you should probably have marked an answer correct and started a new question.  I only saw the change in question because I clicked the link by accident.

Answer (score 6):

For this to work as you describe, the if-structure ...

```
if (highestLevel == 2) {
    $('#button2').show();
}
```

... must be inside the click function. Try ...

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
    Check();
    highestLevel = 2;
    $('#button2').show();
});
```

You really don't need the if-structure doing it this way ... in your code, the if-structure only runs on document-ready (ONE TIME).

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken about what is happening.  This code block runs when the document is loaded, not after button1 is clicked.

You want to put it inside the click function

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
  Check();
  highestLevel = 2;

  if (highestLevel == 2) {
    $('#button2').show();
  }
})
```

You will also want to prevent the default action of the button, which is to post the page causing it to reload, by adding an event object

```
$('#button1').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Check();
  highestLevel = 2;

  if (highestLevel == 2) {
    $('#button2').show();
  }
})


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all of that... The problem is that

```
if (highestLevel == 2) {
    $('#button2').show();
}
```

executes only once, when the document is ready.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button2').hide();

  $('#button1').click(function () {
     $('#button2').show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this**

```
        window.highestLevel = localStorage.getItem('highestLevel');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (highestLevel == 2) {
                $('#button2').show();
                $('#button1').hide();
            }
            else {
                highestLevel == 1
                $('#button1').show();
                $('#button2').hide();
            }

            $('div').click(function () {
                if (highestLevel == 2) {
                     highestLevel = 1;
                    $('#button1').show();
                    $('#button2').hide();
                }
                else{
                    highestLevel = 2;
                    $('#button2').show();
                    $('#button1').hide();
                }
                Check();
            });
        });


        function Check() {
            localStorage.setItem('highestLevel', highestLevel);
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure where I should put that TBH can you do that in a fiddle thank you.

Comment: I understand that you want something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/diegordzr/cbyLw4ea/1/)